# .Net load file or assembly error

Tags: .net, mysql, sql

I am trying to run a .Net application's .exe file from bin/Debug folder but it gives me an error like

> Cannot load file or assembly "Mysql.Data version=6.2.2.0",culture=neutral publicKeyToken=c5.... or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified"

I haven't worked on .Net before can anyone help ???

Comment: and is Mysql.Data.dll in the folder?

Comment: No.I have searched it in the entire project folder it isnt there...

Comment: I have downloaded the .dll 1.0.10.0 and copied into debug folder but no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you the problem; it can't find `Mysql.Data.dll`. There are two (main) ways it can get this:

- installed into the GAC (a pain to do, frankly)
- in the same folder (bin/Debug in this case)

to achieve the latter, simply expand "references" in the solution explorer, find `Mysql.Data`, and then (in the properties pane) ensure "Copy Local" is set to "True". Then rebuild, and the file should appear.

Comment: @user418232 I assumed you did; now, when you build - it is getting that dll from *somewhere*. The "Copy Local" *should* be enough here.

Comment: I have downloaded the .dll 1.0.10.0 and copied into debug folder but no success

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to install the mysql connector. it also intalls everything you need into the gac.

you can download it here http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.3.html#downloads

cheers

Comment: The installer says says 'The installation package could not be opened.Contact vendor'

Comment: whats your os? did you check your event logs? maybe there is some more detailed error description, otherwise try to download it again..